# How to view cookies when using iPhone Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I would like to view the cookies being stored when I visit a webpage through the iPhone simulator. I am currently using Xcode 7.3.1 Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Safari web inspector also works remotely: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: That is a big help! Any idea where I can see them being stored locally though?